# Anime scene with DNA helix changing

Tags: story-identification, anime

There's a scene from an anime I'm trying to find but I don't remember which anime it was. I think it was an MC getting a power-up or something and it showed his DNA changing.

Does anyone know what anime it could have been?

Comment: This sounds far too vague and non-specific to be answerable, I'm afraid. I'm sure there must be multiple different anime with such a scene.

Comment: Sounds like Spider-Man 1

Comment: [Danny Phantom](https://dannyphantom.fandom.com/wiki/Half-ghost)?

Comment: Isekai cheat skill.. and Arafuretta spring immediately to mind. Perhaps you could describe the MC appearance before and after, secondary characters could also help. Is it a sci-fi, fantasy, isekai theme? Do you remember approximately when you saw it?